# PowerShell Script for Bamboo to deploy a windows service to our QA server

Tags: powershell, windows-services, bamboo, deployment-project

I am new to powershell and I'm writing a script to be used in Bamboo to deploy a windows service to our QA server. So far I have this:

```
$serviceName = '${bamboo.ServiceName}'
$exePath = "path to executable on QA server"
$username = "username"
$password = convertto-securestring -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force 
$credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
$existingService = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name = '$serviceName' "
$MSDeploy = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe"

invoke-command -ComputerName [COMPUTER] -Credential $credentials -scriptblock { [STATEMENT TO EXECUTE] }

if($existingService)
{
    " '$serviceName' currently exists, stopping service now."
    Stop-Service $serviceName
    "Waiting 5 seconds for service to stop"
    Start-Sleep -s 5

    $existingService.Delete()
    "Waiting 5 seconds for service to uninstall"
    Start-Sleep -s 5
}
```

I know I need to install the new service and was planning on doing it with the $MSBuild variable, but should I be attaching the $exepath variable to the end of it as well? Or would that just reinstall the current service again?